# Preventing effects from over laying?

Tags: c#, image, effect

So basically I've got 2 effects. 1 is Sepia and the other is some Aqua effect, when I put the Aqua effect onto the image and then go to put the Sepia effect onto it the Sepia effect will overlay the Aqua. I don't understand why it is doing it, I know to add an additional picture box to it and make the picturebox invisible but this isn't an efficient way of doing it, their must be another more efficient way of doing it, can anyone please share?

**Sepia**

```
private void btnGrayscale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Bitmap grayScale = (Bitmap)picOriginal.Image.Clone();
int height = grayScale.Size.Height;
int width = grayScale.Size.Width;    
for (int yCoordinate = 0; yCoordinate < height; yCoordinate++)

{

for (int xCoordinate = 0; xCoordinate < width; xCoordinate++)

{
Color color = grayScale.GetPixel(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
int grayColor = (color.R + color.G + color.B) / 3;
grayScale.SetPixel(xCoordinate, yCoordinate,     Color.FromArgb(grayColor,grayColor,grayColor));

 }

} 
 picModified.Image = grayScale;
```

}

**Aqua**

```
 ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
 new float[] {0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
 new float[] {0, 0, 4, 0, 4},
 new float[] {0, 0, 0, 4, 0},
 new float[] {     0,      0,      4, 0, 1},
  new float[] {     0,      0,      0, 4, 0}
 });

 Image image = (Bitmap)picOriginal.Image.Clone();
 ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
 attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix);
 Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
 graphics.DrawImage(image,

 new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),0,0,image.Width,image.Height,
 GraphicsUnit.Pixel,attributes);

 graphics.Dispose();


 picModified.Image = image;


 }
```

Comment: Very unclear what your problem is - you have one image and apply 2 effects to it in a sequence - so both effects will be applied (which is reasonable to me). Can you please clarify what you expect as result of applying 2 effects? Side note: please edit you sample to remove comments and whitespaces.

Comment: Side note on code comments: please in general avoid comments that say exactly the same as code next to it. I.e. `a=a+1;//add 1 to "a"`, or in your sample "//Get the pixel that's at our current coordinate" next to line of code that does *exactly* that `grayScale.GetPixel(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);`)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `a=a+1;//add 1 to "a"`. Hahaha Epic.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Its updated! Basically, the effects go on top of eachother and I dont want it to do that, is their any way in stopping it doing this? When I apply an effect I just want it to show that effect rather than it overlaying ontop of another effect

Comment: `their must be another more efficient way of doing it` - Yes, it's called [WPF](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Continuum/WPFFXDemo/). You should avoid trying to reinvent the wheel. Microsoft already did that, and they know much better than any of us.

Comment: I just need help, perhaps I could make IF statements.. god knows